# ¿Error en consulta de SQLite? "no such table: Tabla (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Campo from Tabla"

Tags: java, android

Hola tengo una base de datos en `SQLite`, y estoy tratando de consultar un campo `integer` llamado Tipo para hacer una comparación con los case de un `switch`, pero me muestra el error:

> no such table: Tabla (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Campo from
>   Tabla

este es mi código:

```
Cursor cursor=null;
int x=0;
try {
bd=con.getReadableDatabase();
cursor= bd.rawQuery("SELECT Tipo from Tabla", null);//error
x=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}

SQLiteDatabase bd1 = con.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
if(cursor!=null) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
 switch (x) {
     case 1:
     ....
     break;
     }
 }
 ......
```

Base de datos

```
public class conexion extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public conexion(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
        {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
           sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Tabla.crearT);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists " + Tabla.tabl);

           onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }
    }
```

Tabla

```
public class Creditos_Gestiones {
    //constante campos tabla
    public static final String tabl="Tabla";
    public static final String id="id";
    public static final String Tipo="Tipo";
    public static final String User="User";
    public static final String Nombre="User";

    public static final String creaT = "create table Tabla" + tabl + "(" +id + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + Tipo +" integer, " + User + " integer, " +Nombre+ " text)";
}
```

Comment: buenas, tu tabla se llama "Tabla"?

Comment: @JulianYbarra hola, tiene otro nombre solo le puse asi para publicarlo

Comment: creería que no encuentra tu "Tabla" en la base de datos, esto puede ser por que ya hallas creado la BD y cuando agregaste la "Tabla" por código, la BD no se modifico, lo cual puede ser por la versión de la BD,

Comment: @JulianYbarra entonces que podria hacer? :(

Comment: puedes agregar tu clase de BD? es con SQLiteOpenHelper? estas en produccion? o lo estas desarrollando todavia?

Comment: @JulianYbarra ya he agregado el codigo, si aun estoy desarrollando

Comment: @Geek revisa el query para crear la tabla, he agregado respuesta Geek.

Comment: me paso que me aparecia no such table: nombre_de_la_tabla y era por que no habia echo las migraciones. > py manage.py makemigrations
> > py manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es en la consulta, se encuentra en el query que tienes definido para crear la tabla:

```
 public static final String creaT = "create table Tabla" + tabl + "(" +id + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + Tipo +" integer, " + User + " integer, " +Nombre+ " text)";
```

en realidad esto no esta creando la tabla por esa razón obtienes el error:

> "no such table: Tabla (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Campo from
>   Tabla"

debe ser:

```
 public static final String creaT = "create table " + tabl + " (" +id + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + Tipo +" integer, " + User + " integer, " +Nombre+ " text)";
```

Después de corregir el query debes eliminar la aplicación e instalala nuevamente o elimina el caché para evitar información que pudiera ser corrupta.

Comment: Gracias exactamente eso era

Comment: Excelente @Geek, saludos!